# is it possible to call a class inside a switch statement in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, browser-automation

This is C# selenium webdriver automation.
I have created a script in C# that runs and gives me a report on a webpage.
However The user can select 10 different links to create a report within the page.
I need to do this for 10 other links so technically only 1 line changes inside the script.

Is there a way to keep 1 script and just call a method in a switch (case ) scenario using the class of each link (The class determines which test case to run) as my parameter? Or do i need to write the script 10 times for each link?

```
public static string ProCenter_Top40_Programs_Careers(IWebDriver driver, string baseURL, string filepath, string UserName, string Password, string LastName, string FirstName)
        {
            string PassScreenPrintFilePath;
            XapQA.Transitions.Common.ProCenter_SignIn(driver, baseURL, UserName, Password, FirstName, LastName);
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Reports")).Click();
            driver.waitForPageToLoad();
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Create a New Report")).Click();
            driver.waitForPageToLoad();
            //TODO: Add a switch case that tells me wich type of report i want.
            string method = 
            //This is what I want to change
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Top 40 Saved Programs/Majors")).Click();
            driver.waitForPageToLoad();
```

Comment: I think you need to add some code so we can understand better what you're asking.

Comment: If your classes are members of the same interface, and the interface signature contains the single command. Should be pretty easy.

Comment: sorry first time posting, so relatively new to this. The bold line is the only line that I would need to change, so my idea is to turn that line into a switch statement and verify the switch statement using the class as my parameters.

Comment: @user2961832, Please use the "code block" markup in the future. It is much easier to read! I have fixed this one for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleaner option would be to add the string value as a parameter.

```
public static string RunReport(....., string reportLinkText)
{
    /* Code as before, except: */
    driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(reportLinkText)).Click();
}
```

then

```
public static string ProCenter_Top40_Programs_Careers(...)
{
    RunReport(..., "Top 40 Saved Programs/Majors");
}
```